# acknowledgments in latex

Tags: latex

I'm in a `\documentclass{article}` in Latex. How would I put the name of an advisor on the first page? I've seen examples in latex for things like `\principaladvisor{}` but that seems to be done with the thesis class. I'm guessing with the article class I'd list the advisor as a co-author or something. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Listing an advisor as a co-author is of course the easiest possibility :).

Another way of mentioning your advisor is by using a `\thanks{}` environment. It will be displayed in a footnote on your title page that case.

If you really want more flexibility, you can create your own titlepage. Wikibooks has a nice starting point for this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation